# Natural Log using Gurobi package in Python 3

Tags: python, gurobi

```
from gurobipy import *
from math import *

def main():

    # Create a new model

    m = Model()

    # Create variables

    lb = 0.0
    ub = 1.0

    x = m.addVar(lb, ub, name='x')
    y = m.addVar(lb, ub, name='y')

    # Set objective for y

    m.setObjective(y)


    m.addConstr(log(x) + 2 * y + 3 <= 4, 'c0')

    # Add constraint: x + y >= 1

    m.addConstr(x + y >= 1, 'c1')

    # Optimize model as an LP

    m.optimize()

main()
```

I am trying to solve a utility optimization problem, but it keep creates an error that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python36/gur.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/python36/gur.py", line 38, in main
    m.addConstr(log(x) + 2 * y + 3 <= 4, 'c0')
TypeError: must be real number, not Var
```

I have been searching and reading over several websites, but I could not find a clear solution yet.

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: Gurobi can't do logarithms. Only linear, quadratic, and piecewise linear.

Comment: You're passing a gurobi `Var` to `math.log`, which knows nothing about it, so you're getting an error from `math.log`.